# How to use SIFT algorithm in php

Tags: php, wordpress, sift, image-comparison, asift

I am creating WordPress plugin in php so I need to use SIFT algorithm for image comparison from database, but I did not find any SIFT algorithm library in php, only available in c and c++. I have tried to search in google but not get success. Somewhere I read that "*SIFT algorithm implementation in php is very complicate and approximate impossible to use in  production so use c or c++ library.*"  But I can not change programing language and not able to create php extension. So I have few questions,

1: It is possible to implement SIFT algorithm in php, if yes then any php library available for that?

2: It is possible to use c++ library in php without creating php extension, for example Run command line c++ in php and get output. any c or c++ library available for SIFT algorithm to use in command line?

Comment: there are several resource for PHP the main an OPneCV wrapper for OpenCV   https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP